# grep variable in python

Tags: python, grep

I need something like grep in python
I have done research and found the re module to be suitable
I need to search variables for a specific string

Comment: Nice to know.  Do you happen to have a question about it?

Comment: Have you worked through the Python tutorial?

Answer (score 6):

To search for a specific string within a variable, you can just use `in`:

```
>>> 'foo' in 'foobar'
True
>>> s = 'foobar'
>>> 'foo' in s
True
>>> 'baz' in s
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) will be the easiest way. You can search for just a literal string if that's what you're looking for (although your purpose would be better served by the string `in` operator and you'll need to escape regex characters), or else any string you would pass to `grep` (although I don't know the syntax differences between the two off the top of my head, but I'm sure there are differences).

```
>>> re.findall("x", "xyz")
['x']
>>> re.findall("b.d", "abcde")
['bcd']
>>> re.findall("a?ba?c", "abacbc")
['abac', 'bc']
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you really want is the ability to print a large substring in a way that lets you easily see where a particular substring is. There are a couple of ways to approach this.

```
def grep(large_string, substring):
    for line, i in enumerate(large_string.split('\n')):
        if substring in line:
            print("{}: {}".format(i, line))
```

This would print only the lines that have your substring. However, you would lose a bunch of context. If you want true grep, replace `if substring in line` with something that uses the `re` module to do regular expression matching.

```
def highlight(large_string, substring):
    from colorama import Fore
    text_in_between = large_string.split(substring)
    highlighted_substring = "{}{}{}".format(Fore.RED, substring, Fore.RESET)
    print(highlighted_substring.join(text_in_between))
```

This will print the whole large string, but with the substring you are looking for in red. Note that you'll need to `pip install colorama` for it to work. You can of course combine the two approaches.